# Java - issue with assigning Node

Tags: java, nodes

I have an interesting situation: When I add a node into a queue, only two nodes added.

Here's how I add nodes into a queue:

```
Queue queue = new Queue();
Node a = new Node("1");
Node b = new Node("2");
Node c = new Node("3");
Node d = new Node("4");

queue.add(a);
queue.add(b);
queue.add(c);
queue.add(d);
```

Now, here's the add method:

```
public void add(Node newNode)
{
    // assigning first Node
    if (head == null){
        head = newNode;
    return;
    }

    // since first Node assigned, assigning second one
    if (head.next == null){
        head.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
1
2
```

I want to print all of them, but only first two are printed. Also, it is like stack, but FIFO, not LIFO.

Here's the print if it helps:

```
public void print()
{
    Node p;
    // Display all the nodes in the stack
    for( p = head; p != null; p = p.next )
        p.print();
}
```

Please let me know if additional info needed.
Thanks!

Comment: `// since first Node assigned, assigning second one`. Does that ever change after the 2nd node added?

Comment: Yes, it should get added all the time when new Node added, not only second one, but third, fourth...

Comment: You say **assigning second one**. How is that assigning third, fourth?

Comment: That is the mistake, please disregard and take as adder, so that it should add further Node additions.

Comment: If your queue already has two elements, it will check the head, not enter the if, then check the second element, and not enter the second if, and exit. You need to somehow always get to the end of the queue, not just to the second element.

Comment: Guys, thanks to all of you for your immediate help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) is a FIFO data structure, the first element added to the queue will be the first one to be removed. In a Queue, you add elements from rear end while you remove elements from the head. Every time you add an element, you just need to move the rear pointer, while you remove an element, you need to move the head pointer.

Try this:

```
public void add(Node newNode)
{
    // assigning first Node
    if (head == null){
        head = newNode;
        rear = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // since first Node assigned, use rear pointer for assignment
    rear.next=newNode;
    rear = newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a *recursive* approach:

```
public void add(Node newNode) {
    // assigning first Node
    if (next == null) {
        next = newNode;
    } else {
        next.add(newNode); // recursive call
    }
}
```

This method walks along the chain of nodes until it finds the tail, then adds the node there.

The first call is to the head:

```
head.add(newNode);
```

The recursive form of the method will take care of the rest.

You only update the head when you take from the head of the queue - you take the head and update the reference to be `head.next`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code carefully, you are only updating the head and its next pointer.

A solution would be to include a secondary pointer called `current` where you can update `current.next` to the `newNode` and set `current` to `newNode` after doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code

```
// since first Node assigned, assigning second one
if (head.next == null){
    head.next = newNode;
}
```

You're always only going to assign the second node when there isn't a second node, and it won't work for the third node and so on, change it to:

```
// since first Node assigned, assigning next one
Node x = head;    // Start from head
while(x.next != null){
    x = x.next;   // Find the last node in the queue
}
x.next = newNode;  // Link the new node to the last node
```

Another simplification is to always keep a pointer to the last node in the queue. So you can replace the above code with:

```
public void add(Node newNode)
{
    // assigning first Node
    if (head == null){
        head = last = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // since first Node assigned, assigning to end of queue
    last.next = newNode
    last = last.next;
}
```

This will be much faster